# My android app is getting crashed and started rebooting continuously till uninstalling it?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-canvas

I am creating a canvas android application and it is working good for sometime time after that I am getting a message that unfortunately your application has been stopped.After pressing the ok button it is getting started again and I am continuously getting the message that your application has been stopped.

I am sure about the activity closing and I am using n number(75 images) of images in this.. my app memory size is 12MB .

Could someone tell me how to resolve this problem.

Here is my code ,

```
public class CharactersCanvas extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    Context context;
    int newFrameImageId;
    int newFrameIndex;
    static List<Integer> listFlag;
    DrawingPanel dp;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public int key;
    public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>> pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>>();
    static public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Path> recPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    HashMap hMap = new HashMap();
    FrameLayout frmLayout;
    Canvas canvas;
    Button previousButton;
    Button nextButton;
    protected static ImageView imageView;
    private Integer frameIndex = 0;
    public int res;
    Path mPath;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.character_canvas);
        dp = new DrawingPanel(this);
        frmLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous_buttonn);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_buttonn);
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        frmLayout.addView(dp);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        res = bundle.getInt("resourseInt");
       /*   res=bundle.getInt("GridBack");*/
        int gridViewIndex = bundle.getInt("frameIndex");        
        imageView.setImageResource(res);
        frameIndex = (bundle != null && bundle.getInt("image") != 0) ? HomeScreen.characters
                .indexOf(bundle.getInt("image")) : frameIndex;
        frmLayout.setBackgroundResource((int) HomeScreen.characters
                .get(frameIndex));
        newFrameImageId = (int) HomeScreen.characters.get(frameIndex);
        if (pathMap.containsKey(newFrameImageId)
                && pathMap.get(newFrameImageId) != null) {
            recPaths = pathMap.get(newFrameImageId);
            dp.onClickRedo();
        } else {
            recPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
        }

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_buttonn))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        int currentFrameImageId = (int) HomeScreen.characters
                                .get(frameIndex);
                        if (paths.size() > 0) {                         
                            pathMap.remove(currentFrameImageId);
                        }                       
                        if (dp != null)
                            dp.invalidate();
                        paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
                        if (paths != null) {
                            paths.clear();
                            mPath = new Path();
                            paths.add(mPath);
                        }
                    }
                });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.letters_buttonn))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int currentFrameImageId = (int) HomeScreen.characters.get(frameIndex);

                        if (paths.size() > 0) {
                            pathMap.put(currentFrameImageId, paths);
                        } else {
                            pathMap.remove(currentFrameImageId);
                        }
                        paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
                        mPath = new Path();
                        paths.add(mPath);
                        if (paths != null) {
                            paths.clear();
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                CharactersGridView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("resourseInt", res);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.home_buttonn))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (paths != null) {
                            paths.clear();
                            pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>>();
                        }
                        startActivity(new Intent(CharactersCanvas.this,
                                HomeScreen.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (paths != null) {
                paths.clear();
                pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>>();
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(CharactersCanvas.this, HomeScreen.class));
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Paint mPaint, circlePaint, outercirclePaint;
        boolean validateEvent;

        public boolean isValidateEvent() {
            return validateEvent;
        }

        public void onClickLogic(View arg0, boolean isNextFlag) {
            int currentFrameImageId;

            // Decide if navigation is forward or backward
            if (isNextFlag && frameIndex >= (HomeScreen.characters.size() - 1)) {               
                // Do nothing.
                return;
            }
            // Decide if navigation is forward or backward
            if (!isNextFlag && frameIndex == 0) {
                // Do nothing.              
                return;
            }
            // invalidate DP if it's not null
            if (dp != null)
                dp.invalidate();
            // Store current frame paths

            currentFrameImageId = (int) HomeScreen.characters.get(frameIndex);

            if (paths.size() > 0) {
                pathMap.put(currentFrameImageId, paths);

            } else {
                pathMap.remove(currentFrameImageId);
            }
            paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
            newFrameIndex = frameIndex;
            if (isNextFlag) {
                newFrameIndex++;
            } else {
                newFrameIndex--;
            }
            // Load image for frame
            newFrameImageId = (int) HomeScreen.characters.get(newFrameIndex);
            frmLayout.setBackgroundResource(newFrameImageId);
            // Load path for frame
            if (pathMap.containsKey(newFrameImageId)
                    && pathMap.get(newFrameImageId) != null) {
                recPaths = pathMap.get(newFrameImageId);
                dp.onClickRedo();
            } else {
                recPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
            }
            frameIndex = newFrameIndex;

        }

        public void setValidateEvent(boolean validateEvent) {
            this.validateEvent = validateEvent;
        }

        public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            this.setOnTouchListener(this);
            circlePaint = new Paint(); // paint
            mPaint = new Paint(); // paint
            outercirclePaint = new Paint(); // paint
            outercirclePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            outercirclePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            outercirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            mCanvas = new Canvas();
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (paths != null && paths.size() > 0) {
                for (Path p : paths) {
                    canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onClickRedo() {
            if (recPaths.size() > 0) {          
                paths.addAll(recPaths);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            mPath = new Path();
            paths.add(mPath);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.previous_buttonn:
            dp.onClickLogic(v, false);          
            // DO something
            break;
        case R.id.next_buttonn:
            // DO something
            dp.onClickLogic(v, true);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Home screen code,

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {
    TextView tamil, english, numbers;
    Animation bouncer;
    TextView textDialog;
    protected static ArrayList<Integer> characters;
    protected static ImageView imageView;
    public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>> pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Path>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        characters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        english = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.english_btn);
        tamil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tamil_btn);
        numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_btn);
        /*Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/fontone.ttf");
        english.setTypeface(type);
        tamil.setTypeface(type);
        numbers.setTypeface(type);*/
        textDialog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textVieww1);
        english.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*englishCustomDialog(textDialog);*/

                Class classes;
                try {
                    classes = Class
                            .forName("com.KidsSlate.canvasslate.R$drawable");
                    for (Field field : classes.getFields()) {
                        try {
                            if (field.getName().contains("eng_c")) {
                                characters.add(field.getInt(field.getName()));
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,
                        CharactersCanvas.class);
                intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.eng_a);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        tamil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tamilCustomDialog(textDialog);
            }
        });

        numbers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*numberCustomDialog(textDialog);*/

                Class classes;
                try {
                    classes = Class
                            .forName("com.KidsSlate.canvasslate.R$drawable");
                    for (Field field : classes.getFields()) {
                        try {
                            if (field.getName().contains("number_n")) {
                                characters.add(field.getInt(field.getName()));
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,
                        CharactersCanvas.class);
                intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.num_one_);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    private void tamilCustomDialog(final TextView _textDialog) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HomeScreen.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.tamil_dialog);
        ImageView levelOne = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.uyir);
        ImageView levelTwo = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mei);
        levelOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class classes;
                try {
                    classes = Class
                            .forName("com.KidsSlate.canvasslate.R$drawable");
                    for (Field field : classes.getFields()) {
                        try {
                            if (field.getName().startsWith("tamil_t")) {
                                characters.add(field.getInt(field.getName()));
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,
                        CharactersCanvas.class);
                intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.tamil_a);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        levelTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class classes;
                try {
                    classes = Class
                            .forName("com.KidsSlate.canvasslate.R$drawable");
                    for (Field field : classes.getFields()) {
                        try {
                            if (field.getName().startsWith("mei_")) {
                                characters.add(field.getInt(field.getName()));
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,
                        CharactersCanvas.class);
                intent.putExtra("resourseInt", R.drawable.tamil_ka);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add error log ?

Comment: In emulator it was working good when I am installing in real device os in Tablet or Mobile I am getting this issue .

Comment: so debug on your phone and post logcat error